# How did this output come to be?

Tags: c

I'm trying to self-learn programming, and I'm doing an online quiz. One of the questions I have is finding the output of this code:

```
char *strs[] = { "how", "stunt", "ball", "dalq", 0 }, **pps = strs;
int i = 0;
while (*pps) {
 printf("%c", *(*pps++ + i) + i);
 ++i;
}
```

With the answer being "hunt".

Where did this result come from? I'm mostly confused how the while loop works.

Comment: 't' + 1 == 'u', 'l' + 2 == 'n', 'q' + 3 == 't'

Comment: I suggest to add more variables for intermediate results and run the program in a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to look closely at the operator precedence for `*(*pps++ + i) + 1`. Look closely what is incremented and what is added to what.

Comment: I hope you are aware that you should never write code like this in real world code.

Comment: If we see something like "*(*pps++ + i) + i" during a code review, the review session will be closed immediately and a note is send to HR... Even if it is funny to write such code,it is unreadable and operator precedence must not by fully in every developers brain. Typically compilers emit warnings to set braces... My hint: Stop coding this way!

Comment: I don't think any compiler would warn about `*pps++`; it's pretty idiomatic. Other than that, there is nowhere you could put any parentheses to clarify precedence. I agree that the expression is too complex, and should be decomposed into several lines of code. I guess they wanted to show-off the "power" of C, which you can abuse to create code which can also serve as a brain-teaser.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the program in a debugger, and look at the values of all relevant variables (`pps` and `i`).

If you don't have a debugger (or don't want to use one), you should add `printf` statements into your program instead. To do that, you have to transform it so there are no side-effects from the auto-increment `pps++`:

```
while (*pps) {
 printf("%c", *(*pps + i) + i);
 pps++;
 ++i;
}
```

Then add `printf`:

```
while (*pps) {
 printf("Iteration %d\n", i);
 printf("*pps = %s\n", *pps);
 printf("*pps + i = %s\n", *pps + i);
 // etc
 printf("Going to output char %c\n", *(*pps + i) + i);
 pps++;
 printf("After auto-increment, *pps = %s\n", *pps);
 ++i;
}
```